# How to loop multidimensional array in laravel blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
        array:3 [▼
                "name" => array:3 [▼
                              0 => "user2"
                              1 => "user3"
                              2 => "user4"
                                 ]
                "email" => array:3 [▼
                              0 => "user2@gmail.com"
                              1 => "user3@gmail.com"
                              2 => "user4@gmail.com"
                                  ]
                "phone_number" => array:3 [▼
                              0 => "90352065"
                              1 => "69856352"
                              2 => "903520658"
                                  ]
              ]
```

I'm getting above response from multiple text boxes now I need to loop in view, so How to loop above arrays in view??

how can I display above array values like in below format

```
       User2 details
             name  : user2
             email : user2@gmail.com
             phone_number : 90352065
       User3 details
             name  : user3
             email : user3@gmail.com
             phone_number : 69856352 
       User4 details
             name  : user4
             email : user4@gmail.com
             phone_number : 903520658
```

Comment: Simply, use nested foreach

Comment: How to use nested foreach??I'm new to laravel.

Comment: Please, describe what kind of output you need

Comment: I need to display all names,emails and phone numbers from above response in view,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume below is your array structure

```
$original_array = [
  "name" => [
      "user2","user3","user4"
  ],
  "email" => [
      "user2@gmail.com","user3@gmail.com","user4@gmail.com"
  ],
  "phone_number" => [
    "90352065","69856352","903520658"
  ]
];
```

now to get desired output you can use below code

```
<dl>
@foreach($original_array['name'] as $key => $name)
  <dt>{{ $name }} Details</dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>Name: {{ $name }}</li>
      <li>Email: {{ $original_array['email'][$key] }}</li>
      <li>Phone Number: {{ $original_array['phone_number'][$key] }}</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
@endforeach
</dl>
```

Comment: I don't think this will be human-readable no matter how you will name the variables

Comment: The above answer is correct only, But I want to display in view  like      
 name :user2,email:user2@gmail.com,phone:903520658,                     
 name :user3,email:user3@gmail.com,phone: 69856352 ..

Comment: Please check my question again I have updated.Thank you

Answer (score 4):

kind of

```
@foreach($nameArray as $index => $nameArrayElement)     
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $mainArray['name'][$index] }}</td>       
        <td>{{ $mainArray['email'][$index] }}</td>      
        <td>{{ $mainArray['phone_number'][$index] }}</td>   
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Take in mind that the number of names are equal to the number of rows

Answer (score 1):

In laravel I would use this approach to recurse a nested array in blade:

```
<ul>
@forelse($elements as $key => $item)
    <li>
    @if(is_array($item))
        <strong>{{ $key }}: </strong>
        @include('admin.payments.confirmation-data', ['elements' => $item, 'parentKey' => $key])
    @else
        <strong>{{ $key }}: </strong><span>{{ $item }}</span>
    @endif
    </li>
@empty
    <li>
        <strong>yay {{ $parentKey }}</strong>:<span>[]</span>
    </li>
@endforelse
</ul>
```